# How to solve for equations using lagrangian for this system, or is it not solvable this way?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, string

[image]

How to get the accleration of m1 in the figure using lagrangian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always possible to use langrangian mechanics.

Lagrangian mechanics is only a way to get the equations of motion and in this scenario this is better handled by the method of balancing forces.

U will have 3 generalized coordinates with their corresponding lagrange equations.

These co - ordinates are however bound by constraints :-

∑T. a = 0

This is the string contraint to be used along with lagrange multipliers to free the equations from each other.

They along with the constraint relations are all you need to solve this problem in that manner.

Again newtonian mechanics + string contraint will give same relations faster .This is much harder work but will give you an assured result. In case you are doing this to understand the formalism better then happy solving.

P.S
In case you want information on multiplier method check Goldsteins Classical Mechanics Section 2.4 Page 45.